# opposite of isolate in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The `isolate` function in R shiny makes an observer not depend on the code inside it.

Is there an opposite function - one that makes code inside it not trigger further events?

Comment: I'm going to suggest to use `return` here

Comment: How would `return` help? For example I want to set `input$slider_value <- 10` to a reactive variable `input$slider_value`, but I don't want to cause any observers that depend on it to update this time.

Comment: Input variables are read-only, you cannot change the value of them. What's your purpose? It's not much clear to me from your question.

Comment: @nicola, I see, bad example. Actually I wonder if I can make functions like `updateSelectizeInput` to not trigger other events. Or it could be assingment to non-input reactive variable.

Comment: Build a specific case. `updateSelectizeInput` doesn't trigger other events by itself. I still miss your purpose.

Comment: I have a dynamic server-side `updateSelectizeInput`, and it seems it triggers two update events for the relevant input even when I pass  `choices` and `selected` identical to previous (first the value is updated to the empty string, then to selected value).